# How to get the index value of a list item when its position changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery Sortable and I want to get only the change index value of a list item. Is there any way to do so? Right now I am getting value of all indexes and updating data. I want to get position of only the change index value of li. Here is my jquery script

```
<ul>
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>3</li>
   <li>4</li>
</ul>

    $(function () {

        $("ul").sortable({
            items: "li",
            cursor: 'move',
            update: function () {
                sendOrderToServer();
            }
        });

        function sendOrderToServer() {

            var order = [];
            $('li').each(function (index, element) {
                order.push({
                    position: index + 1
                });
            });

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                url: `${SiteConfig.staticContentBaseUrl}/sortabletable`,
                data: {
                    order: order,
                    _token: $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content')
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response.status == "success") {
                        console.log(response);
                    } else {
                        console.log(response);
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

Comment: Go through basic sorting methods and then construct your jquery code based on that, put it here if there is any issue, we can solve that and even suggest you better ways.

Comment: You might describe your larger goal. Tracking indices may not be the best approach.

Comment: ok let me elaborate what i want to acheive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) function in combination with the `item` which is supplied as a property on the [`update` event's second argument](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update).

```js
let $pets = $("#pets"),
  $report = $("#report");
$pets.sortable({
  update(e, ui){
    let $item = ui.item,
      index = $pets.children().index($item) + 1;
    $report.text( `You ranked ${$item.text()} at number ${index}` );
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<h2>Desired Pets: Rank from most desired (top) to least (bottom)</h2>
<ul id="pets">
<li>Cat</li>
<li>Dog</li>
<li>Hamster</li>
<li>Rabbit</li>
<li>Fox</li>
</ul>
<div id="report"></div>
```

Beyond that, you could just store the index of each item in the list and then do a comparison after an update to see which items changed position. You could even go so far as to store the item's previous position using jQuery's [.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/), though I think you'd be better served in the long run if you followed [MVC design principles](https://www.sitepoint.com/mvc-design-pattern-javascript/) or one of it's many variations.